# jQuery object undefined

Tags: jquery, json

Apologies for asking what's probably a very obvious question, I've been banging my head against this all day + I'm very new to JQuery and JavaScript in general.

I'm running the following:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$.getJSON(
  "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22UTG.L%22)%0A%09%09&format=json&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&callback=?", 
  function(data) {

$.each(data.query.results.row, function(index, item){
    $('#quotes')
    .append(
      $('<p/>')
        .append($('<span class="left"/>').text(item.symbol))
        .append($('<span class="right"/>').text('$'+item.price))
      );
    });

  }
);

});
</script>
```

I get object undefined var name, i = 0, length = object.length; from firebug - can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON structure doesn't know a query.results.row, but a query.results.quote instead. This works:

```
console.log(data);
var quotes = data.query.results.quote;
for (var q in quotes) {
  $('#quotes')
    .append(
      $('<p/>')
      .append($('<span class="left"/>').text(q))
      .append($('<span class="right"/>').text('$' + quotes[q]))
    );
}
});
```

You are not calling a JSON resource, but a JSONP resource. The callback argument of the url should be a function name and you should use $.getScript.

```
myCallback = function(jsonData) {
  ...
}
$.getScript("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22UTG.L%22)%0A%09%09&format=json&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&callback=myCallback");
```

Comment: Not necessarily. jQuery's getJSON will replace ? with a correct callback and create a script element for you.

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the JSON response, `data.query.results.row` is undefined (though `data.query.results` isn't). So you're looping over an undefined property.

You may read through the response's properties by using `console.log(data)` in your callback. Then, [download and install FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox if you haven't done so already and check the console.